# Catalog Price Rule not applying to Downloadable product

Tags: product, catalog-price-rules, downloadable

I'm trying to implement a Catalog Price Rule of 50% on specific category of downloadable product, but it doesn't give implemented.

Here are the basic spec of what I've built so far:

Downloadable product:

- Price set at 0, size you cannot buy the entire set, just the
  different resolution
- Each Product has 4 to 6 possible version of download each with a
  different price

Catalog Price Rule

- Is active and implement on the main website
- Condition is set to the proper category
- Action is apply By Percentage of the original price
- Enable discount to subproduct is enable
- and is apply By Percentage of the original price

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does the Shipping Rule without coupon work for given scenario?

Comment: since it's a download, there's is not shipping

Answer (score 2):

I did the same way as you said , I followed the below link to solve the issue

Please see the screenshot to understand

[image]

The problem is solved now.

Please refer the below link it will solve your issue http://predavlad.com/add-catalog-price-rules-to-downloadable-files/